# How do I save a .pem key to avoid pointing to it when SSHing into a server?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh

AWS supplies a .pem file with an EC2 instance. Is there a way to store it permanently, so that I don't need to reference it each time I try to connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure which key to use for a specific host in your `.ssh/config` file.
Example:

```
Host aws-instance
    HostName <IP or hostname>
    User ubuntu
    IdentityFile /home/username/.ssh/key.pem
```

This even allows you to omit the username when connecting, simply do

```
ssh aws-instance
```

For extensive information about possible configuration options, see https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config